# Error Listening To Socket - Cannot run MOOS-IvP on Beaglebone Black

Tags: sockets, middleware, beagleboneblack

I am attempting to run [MOOS-IvP](http://oceanai.mit.edu/moos-ivp/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.HomePage/) on a Beaglebone Black

On attempting to run the MOOS database it continuously throws the exception

"Exception Thrown in listen loop: Error Listening To Socket. Operation not supported"

This software runs on a Raspberry Pi

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: I can get it to work in Single threaded mode. There is an issue running multiple threads on the BBB

Comment: Ok so after much debugging I have found that when the Listen thread socket is started it starts as a UDP socket (determined using lsof) when it should be a TCP socket. What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and fixed it.

When the socket is created it needs to be TCP. However when getprotobyname(_sName) is called in the XPCGetProtocol class to lookup the correct protocol number in /etc/protocols it returns the value of the previous time it was called, which was when a UDP socket was setup.

To fix it I simply called the function twice, the second time it returns the correct value.

I am not sure why it would return incorrect the first time but this works!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error while working with a BeagleBone Black running Ubuntu 14.04.  However, the solution of running the request twice did not work.  More troubleshooting led me to determine that the one that was supposed to be a TCP socket was opened after another process had opened a UDP socket.  The structure returned by `getprotobyname()` is a pointer to a static location that does not change from call to call, but does get updated with the protocol details (see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.bpxbd00/getprot.htm%23getprot) although for another Unix os).  Therefore, the second call by another process overwrites the original details.

This then gets tested during socket creation in the constructor of `XPCSocket`, and results in creation of a UDP socket where it should have been a TCP socket. This could probably be fixed by adding a lock to this function, but I took the non-blocking approach to initialize the requested protocol using the string the constructor was called with (`_sProtocol`) instead of the one returned in the `socketProtocol` structure.  In addition, I modified the `XPCGetProtocol` class to store the protocol number in a member variable that would not be changed upon subsequent calls to `getprotobyname()`.

My modifications can be found [here](https://github.com/mandad/asv-dev/tree/master/moos-ivp-emily/src/coremods).